# How to select information from tables, if second table has duplicated rows, therefore result is multiplied

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: first has repeated values. Second has almost unique values, but there are some duplicated values. I can't change the tables, all I can is write a query to select how many times value from first table repeated where first_table.value=second_table.value.

1st table is Zone

```
    ╔══════╗
    ║ Zone ║
    ╠══════╣
    ║   1  ║
    ║   2  ║
    ║   1  ║
    ║   3  ║
    ║   1  ║
    ╚══════╝
```

and
2nd is Repeated

```
    ╔══════════╗
    ║ Repeated ║
    ╠══════════╣
    ║    1     ║
    ║    2     ║
    ║    3     ║
    ║    4     ║
    ║    1     ║
    ╚══════════╝
```

I've used this query, but it showed me 6 instead of 3

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Zone) as COUNTING
FROM first_table, second_table 
WHERE Zone = 1 AND Zone=Repeated
```

I do expect to get such result:

```
╔══════════╗
║ Counting ║
╠══════════╣
║    3     ║
╚══════════╝
```

Comment: What does the "3" mean in the result set?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  3 means that value 1 was repeated 3 times in first table, while it was found in the second table.

Comment: No join condition?!? Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN will bring back 2 entries for each from table 2 - ie both records where repeated = 1.
If this is not the behaviour you want, something like this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(Zone) as COUNTING
FROM first_table
WHERE Zone = 1 AND Zone in (SELECT Repeated from second_table)
```

--ie it exists in second_table, but number of occurences there does not matter

Answer (score 0):

I think that the logic you want is to find the count of zone records in the first table which appear in duplicate in the repeated table.  In this case, only the value `1` is repeated, so its count in the zone table is 3.  We can express this logic by joining the `Zone` table to a subquery which finds only duplicate repeated values.  Then, take the count of that result set to arrive at the final answer.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Zone z
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Repeated
    FROM Repeated
    GROUP BY Repeated
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) r
    ON z.Zone = r.Repeated
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the search term = `1` why do you use a join?
Just count the `1`s in the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNTING
FROM first_table 
WHERE Zone = 1
```

If you want to count all the values from `second_table` in `first_table`:

```
SELECT f.Zone, COUNT(*) as COUNTING
FROM first_table f INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Repeated FROM second_table) s
ON s.Repeated = f.Zone
GROUP BY f.Zone
```